# Import table using IMPORTXML xpath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to import a table from the following website 
http://financials.morningstar.com/valuation/price-ratio.html?t=MOS&region=usa&culture=en-US 
using google spreadsheet function ImportXML, I have problems with the xpath I found this one for for the table I am looking for:
 `//*[@id="valuation_history_table"]`.

and I am using this formula`=importXML(A4,"//*[@id="valuation_history_table"]")`

but I get the following error msg:

> Error
>   Formula parse error.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492485/how-to-import-xml-table-google-sheets). Does this provide help?

Answer (score 2):

Your getting a formula parse error because you used double quotes in your xpath - also you wouldnt be able to pull it in anyway - if you want a much lighter , less complicated endpoint use this url instead (all the parameters are basically the same) but you can use xpath `//tr` and get the whole table

```
 =IMPORTXML("http://financials.morningstar.com/valuate/valuation-history.action?&t=XNYS:MOS&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&type=price-earnings","//tr")
```

[image]