# Using =IMPORTXML with google sheets to pull data from Ebay API

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets, ebay-api

I am having trouble figuring out the xpath to pull a couple specific pieces of data from [this ebay xml](http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=BrianHug-SoldHist-PRD-b45f0c74d-cc2eb19b&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=mtg%20Metalwork%20Colossus%20Kaladesh%20-(foil,token,tokens,repack,emblem,bulk,box,deck,ultra%20pro,ultrapro,sleeve,repacks,fat%20pack,oversized,oversize,mtgo,online,dice,custom,play%20mat,booster,playmat,packs,Collectors%20Edition,Collector%27s,shirt,lot,altered,mind%20seize,display%20promo,stand,worlds%20promo,championship,proxy,gb)&itemFilter%280%29.name=ListingType&itemFilter%280%29.value=FixedPrice&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1) into a google sheet using the ImportXML function.

I currently am using "/*/*/*/*" as the xpath and am able to pull all the data from the page. But I need to just get 2 pieces of information: convertedCurrentPrice and shippingServiceCost (as shown in the screenshot provided).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Screenshot: Desired Data Marked with Red]

Comment: post xml code rather than picture

Comment: I linked to it in the post. It is an API pull so I have a URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Import XML table Google Sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492485/how-to-import-xml-table-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those that replied. I actually figured out that since it is raw XML data, I need to use a google apps script with XmlService.parse(), getChild(), etc to pull data out and write it to the spreadsheet.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/